# How to display sqlite data in HTML

Tags: html, sqlite, local, reveal.js, sql.js

I am currently looking for a solution to display my data from a SQLite database in a HTML layout. I do link the idea of `reveal.js` and would like to use this or any similar solution as a form for data presentation.

For the first step I do want to have a solution which is able to run offline on every user PC (it may need some pre-installations, but best would be to run in a plain browser) in a second step I may make it accessible via a webserver.

My problem description:

- I do have datasets stored in a local SQLite database file
- I want the data from SQLite to be displayed in HTML
- I want do be able to adapt the data within a HTML form and write back to the database
- I want to have it running locally, but have the possibility to bring it online later

A possible solution I tried:

As I tried to use `reveal.js` to display my data in an appropriate way I am forced to use `JavaScript`. But as far as I know I am not able to access my local SQLite db file from `JavaScript` itself therefore I used an `<input>` form to load the whole database into RAM and then used `SQL.js` to access the database. But as `SQL.js` does only create a copy of my database this is not a real database access and does not allow me to write back any data to the database.

At the moment I ran out of ideas how to solve my problem.

Any thoughts by the community how I may solve my problem? Am I missing anything? 
Or is there a better approach to my problem describe above?

Thanks for any hints, questions, links or whatever.